# Checking for a maximum level of indentation in Checkstyle

Tags: checkstyle

I want to ensure that my code does not exceed 5 levels of indentation, like so:

```java
class Foo { // 0
    void bar() { // 1
        if () { // 2
            if () { // 3
                if () { // 4
                    if () { // 5
                        if () { // 6 - error
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Looking through the Checkstyle documentation, I couldn't find a rule that specifically implements this. Does such a rule exist, or do I have to look into custom rules?

Comment: Doesn't answer the question directly, but in PMD (another static code analysis plugin) this rule is implemented natively for if, for and whiles, so if adding a new plugin is an option you may want to have a look at it

Comment: https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/apidocs/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/checks/metrics/CyclomaticComplexityCheck.html !?

Comment: According/equivalent in pmd: https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_rules_apex_design.html#cyclomaticcomplexity

Comment: Not "specifically this", but closest/most related (as I'm  aware)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an issue still in "Open" state about this feature: https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues/5487

Not exactly what you need, but you can achieve something similar using the [NestedForDepth](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/config_coding.html#NestedForDepth), [NestedIfDepth](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/config_coding.html#NestedIfDepth) and [NestedTryDepth](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/config_coding.html#NestedTryDepth) checks.